# Getting mail properties of the currently selected mail

Tags: mutt

How can I retrieve properties (e.g. subject and certain headers) of a currently "active" mail? By active I mean that the "cursor" is over the email (in the image mail #50).

Whether the mail has been opened or not doesn't matter, it should work in either case.

[image],

The use case is that I want to extract the subject, message-id and in-reply-to headers, so I can ignore all mails with the subject in the thread.

Comment: What do you mean by “retrieve” here? Do you want to restrict the view to emails with(out) certain header values? What you do with the result of the search matters, mutt isn't good at manipulating complex data structures like lists of emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`macro index ,h '<pipe-message> ~/script.sh<enter>' 'Header'`

With `script.sh` being:

```
#!/bin/sh
while IFS= read -r foo
do
echo "$foo" | grep -E 'Message-ID|Date|X-Mailer'
done
```

Adjust the grep to whatever headers you want to see.

Comment: That displays those headers, it doesn't retrieve them in a useful way for further processing. Besides, it's a strange way to do it, why are you calling `grep` on each line individually?

Comment: Sorry, but I understood you wanted to *see* those values. I do not know if and how mutt can reference parts of an email (what you want is `l ~h <curr-message>Message-ID`), my idea would be to construct a `limit` command with a script (similar to above) and then `source` and then `<enter-command>` it. But someone with better mutt foo might know a shortcut. Oh and the script is a snippet what I have in my yasnippet for generic use, I would assume that someone that uses mutt can rewrite shell scripts. ;-)